# Setting CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER to True throws Errors

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have some asynchronous calls in my code. Like this:

```
send_message_to_install.delay(install, alert.message, badge, code,
                            campaign=alert.campaign, **kwargs)
```

I am not interested in getting any results back, its just important that the function is executed synchronously while running the tests - without throwing errors.

While testing, I tried to set CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER in my settings file to True:

```
if "test" in sys.argv:
    CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```

I have tried to set it in the tests as well:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```

Both attempts make my tests throw errors (without the ".delay" it works fine):

```
File "/opt/src/slicephone/cloud/users/api.py", line 520, in send_alert
campaign=alert.campaign, **kwargs)
File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 357, in delay
return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 463, in apply_async
options = router.route(options, self.name, args, kwargs)
File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/routes.py", line 44, in route
route = self.lookup_route(task, args, kwargs)
File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/routes.py", line 77, in lookup_route
return _first_route(self.routes, task, args, kwargs)
File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/functional.py", line 196, in _matcher
answer = getattr(maybe_promise(obj), method)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 50, in maybe_promise
return value.evaluate()
File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/functional.py", line 162, in evaluate
self._value = super(mpromise, self).evaluate()
File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 22, in evaluate
return self._fun(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 48, in instantiate
return symbol_by_name(name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 80, in symbol_by_name
module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)

ImportError: No module named tasks
```

Thanks, Kev

Comment: Where is your `send_message_to_install` located?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. There was a 'messages.tasks' in my CELERY_ROUTES. But no file /messages/tasks.py .

Comment: Thanks for posting back!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CeleryTestRunner](https://django-celery.readthedocs.org/en/2.4/reference/djcelery.contrib.test_runner.html) for testing purposes. 
It will automatically  run your tests in ALWAYS_EAGER mode